# How exactly do I get Facebook to link my friends to iPhoto's Faces tags when sharing from iPhoto?

Tags: macos, photos.app, photos, facebook

I'm preparing to upload an iPhoto event to Facebook for the first time (I'm using iPhoto '11 and my Mac runs Mac OS X 10.7), except I can't quite get Facebook to turn iPhoto's Faces tags into links to my friends' profiles.

Basically, uploading causes the tags on Facebook to show up by themselves without linking to the right profiles. This also means photos of me show up as me... with myself! Like a stunt double, or a clone or something. Anyway, this renders them effectively useless in a sense, as I end up having to manually retag on my browser and remove the tags that came from iPhoto.

Every person's face in this event has been tagged, which is one thing, and I've also tried assigning their Facebook email addresses to their contact cards in iPhoto (which is mentioned in [this Apple guided tour](https://www.apple.com/findouthow/photos/#facebook)). I also found [this Apple document](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=iPhoto/9.0/en/pht6d606d83.html) that suggests signing into Facebook first, then naming faces using Facebook name suggestions. I tried it and then attempted to upload again, but with no luck either.

What exactly do I need to do to get this to work? Or *(hopefully not)* was anything changed in iPhoto or Facebook that means this integration will no longer work correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bit the bullet, and went with the following 4 Rs:

1. Removed all faces from iPhoto who were participating in the event
2. Removed my Facebook account
3. Reauthenticated my account
4. Restored (manually, one by one) the faces, making sure to use Facebook's name suggestions

And Facebook finally recognized and tagged my friends with links to their profiles correctly. Huzzah!